# Вывод элементов инфоблока на странице

Tags: php, битрикс

Доброе утро,

Имеется инфоблок с баннерами и свойством Расположение баннера (верхний баннер, средний баннер, нижний баннер). Необходимо на главной странице вывести 3 баннера, т.е. последний добавленный баннер в зависимости от его расположения.

Вот мой result_modifier.php

```
foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem):

    if($arItem["PROPERTIES"]["BANNER_POSITION"]["VALUE_XML_ID"] == "TOP"):
        $arResult["ITEMS"]["TOP"][] = $arItem;
    elseif($arItem["PROPERTIES"]["BANNER_POSITION"]["VALUE_XML_ID"] == "MIDDLE"):   
        $arResult["ITEMS"]["MIDDLE"][] = $arItem;
    elseif($arItem["PROPERTIES"]["BANNER_POSITION"]["VALUE_XML_ID"] == "BOTTOM"):
        $arResult["ITEMS"]["BOTTOM"][] = $arItem;
    endif;

endforeach;
```

И сам template.php

```
<div class="banner middle">

    <?foreach($arResult["ITEMS"]["MIDDLE"] as $arItem):?>

    <?if(SITE_TEMPLATE_ID == 'mobile')$arItem["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["SRC"] = $arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["SRC"];?>

    <div id="<?=$this->GetEditAreaId($arItem['ID']) ;?>" title="<?=$arItem["DETAIL_PICTURE"]['TITLE']?>" alt="<?=$arItem["DETAIL_PICTURE"]['ALT']?>" style="background: url(<?=$arItem['DETAIL_PICTURE']['SRC']?>) no-repeat center center; display: block; background-size: cover; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>

    <?endforeach;?>
</div>
```

Кто подскажет как здесь быть?

Буду благодарен.

Comment: Как хотите, так и будьте)

Comment: выборка нужных баннеров в вашем случае делается на уровне mysql запроса

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка была в параметре NEWS_COUNT = 1. Нужно удалить этот параметр из компонента.